# How to make youtube embedded video load only when box appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

In my code, youtube video appears in a pop-up window, when users click on a button.

[This is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/)

I want the video to load only when someone click on the button and pop-up window appears, and it to stop playing, when someone close the box.

Currently,my code just hide the display, nothing more than that.

HTML:

```
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>


<div id="close">
<div id="trailerdivbox" >
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" frameborder="0" 
 allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */
#watchbutton {
background-color:#f2f2f2;
color:red;
font-weight:600;
border: none; /* This one removes the border of button */
padding: 10px 12px;

}

#watchbutton:hover {
background-color:#e2e2e2;
cursor:pointer;
}

 #trailerdivbox {
display:none;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
overflow: auto; /* Enable Scrolling */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */


}

 .videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
 }
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
max-width:560px;
max-height:315px;
width: 95%;
height: 95%;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
 btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }

 var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

 trailerbox.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

Comment: On button click and modal opening add the following
`btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-large-play-button ytp-button")[0].click();
 }`

Comment: Trigger a click event on the iframe that opens inside modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?autoplay=1` to your iframe `src`.

And *reset* the `src` to stop the video.

To load the `iframe` source only on button click, instead of loading it on document load, you should set the `src` attribute on `playVideo()` function.

For that, you can add a new attribute to your `iframe` (`data-src`), which will store the video URL, and then, access it's value when needed.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");

function playVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.dataset.src;

  video.src = src + '?autoplay=1';
}

function resetVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

  video.src = '';
  video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  playVideo();
}

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetVideo();
  }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

#watchbutton {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  /* This one removes the border of button */
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

#watchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable Scrolling */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>


<div id="close">
  <div id="trailerdivbox">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe id="video" class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/3/) if you can't play the video in the snippet above.

Comment: Hey bro, it is working. The video gets closed. But, how to make it so the video only load when the pop-up box appear?

Comment: Isn't it working like that already? The video autoplays only when you load the pop-up.

Comment: Yes, the video autoplays when the pop-up box open. That is not what i want. 

I want, the video to load (whole iframe) only when someone click on the watch video button. 

The iframe load in the background, without clicking on the watch video button, it makes the page load time a bit slow + increases user's data usage

Comment: Oh, i see. I have updated the answer. Please, see if this is what you need.

Comment: Working, thanks a lot man. You really took a lot of time to help me, very very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, dude.

Answer (score 0):

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/3J2wT/) API Doc of youtube [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls)

```
player.stopVideo()
```

So in Jquery

```
$('#ID').get(0).stopVideo();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="stop" href="#">Stop</a>

<iframe id="popup-youtube-player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/geTgZcHrXTc?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>


$('#stop').on('click', function() {
    //$('#popup-youtube-player').stopVideo();
$('#popup-youtube-player')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');    });
```