# How to load a iframe only on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want a youtube video Iframe only when "Watch Video" Button is clicked. Currently the video iframe loads in the background, when the page loads.

Note: I do not mean, play the video on button click. I mean, load the iframe on button click

https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

#watchbutton {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  /* This one removes the border of button */
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

#watchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable Scrolling */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>

<div id="close">
  <div id="trailerdivbox">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try settings the `src` on the button click, instead of adding it directly in the HTML. [Here is example](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/4/)

Comment: I have already answered this question. Why did you create the same question again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make youtube embedded video load only when box appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261902/how-to-make-youtube-embedded-video-load-only-when-box-appears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `src` attribute to a `data-src`, then when you click the button, set `src` to `data-src`

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");

var trailer = document.getElementById('trailervideo');

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  trailer.setAttribute('src', trailer.getAttribute('data-src'));
}

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

#watchbutton {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  /* This one removes the border of button */
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

#watchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable Scrolling */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>


<div id="close">
  <div id="trailerdivbox">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe id="trailervideo" class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do is add the `src` attribute when clicking the "Watch Trailer" button! :)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");



// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";



    //Add "src" attribute by getting the video and setting it with setAttribute.
    document.getElementsByClassName('trailervideo')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw');



}

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */
#watchbutton {
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 color:red;
 font-weight:600;
 border: none; /* This one removes the border of button */
 padding: 10px 12px;

}

#watchbutton:hover {
 background-color:#e2e2e2;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
 display:none;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 overflow: auto; /* Enable Scrolling */
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
 
 
}

.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 max-width:560px;
 max-height:315px;
 width: 95%;
 height: 95%;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>


<div id="close">
<div id="trailerdivbox" >
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```