# iFrame visible on load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My iframe webpage gets visible as soon as I load my HTML page. I do not want this to happen. It should only display on click of a button. Why is this happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <body>
    <form> <button type="button" id="Open_Frame" onclick="show_iframe">Files</button> </form>
    <iframe id="iframe"
  src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
  style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: 100px;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
  ">
   </iframe>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
function show_iframe() {
    //Display iframe on click
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a iframe only on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266225/how-to-load-a-iframe-only-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach for this "hide and display" feature is by changing the CSS property [display or visibility](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-visibility.php)(depends on whether you wanna keep the space of the element after hiding it) of the element.

Visibility of an HTML element is set to visible as default, thus the iframe will always be shown by default.

Also, you missed a **()** after your function **show_iframe** for the onclick event listener.

A working example is as below:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form> <button type="button" id="Open_Frame" onclick="show_iframe()">Files</button> </form>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: 100px;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    display: None;
    margin-top: 35px;
  ">
   </iframe>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  function show_iframe() {
    let myIframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    if (myIframe.style.display == 'block')
      myIframe.style.display = 'None';
    else
      myIframe.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot! I completely forgot about the display. I have another issue, this button gets hidden behind the iframe. So I would like to add another button that is on top of the iframe to close the window. How do i do this?

Comment: You need to change the layout a bit. One way to solve the problem is to add some margin between iframe and button.